# App crashes with ClassNotFoundException after updating Android Studio to 2.3.1 and gradle to

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I updated Android studio yesterday to 2.3.1 and gradle wrapper to gradle-3.3-all. After updating my app stopped building properly and keep crashing after installing in device.

Stacktrace is

```
04-16 19:37:19.436 ? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-16 19:37:23.620 ? E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
                                        java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:173)
                                            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
                                            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:285)
                                            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$5.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:269)
                                            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:30)
                                            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 19:37:23.622 ? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp.ui.ScrMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp.ui.ScrMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp.ui.ScrMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/tk.swapnilUtilities.myApp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using kotlin version '1.1.1', 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1', 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0', compileSdkVersionValue = 25, buildToolsVersionValue = '25.0.2'

I tried installing the app using gradlew installMockDebug but it fails to run. 
I disabled instant run as mentioned in other posts but no help. Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT:
My build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersionValue
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersionValue

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tk.swapnilUtilities"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersionValue
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en", "hi"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        /*jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }*/
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        mock {
        }
        api {

        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    /*compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile rootProject.ext.recyclerview
    compile 'com.github.zhaokaiqiang.klog:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'

    //Testing
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // Android runner and rules support
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    // Espresso support
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
    // Firebase Authentication
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'
    //RX
    //compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.+'
    //compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.+'
    //compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7'
    /*compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'*/
    compile rootProject.ext.rxJava
    compile rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    //Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin_version}"
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile project(':pickphotos')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force rootProject.ext.annotations
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: Please post your app `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this issue. The app was working fine when installed via Android Studio. However, when installed by clicking on the apk file (for instance, when the apk is shared via email), the app crashes with ClassNotFoundException on app launch.

Was able to resolve this by building the apk using,
Build > Build APK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chanage this file
**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```